# stackdriver logs in case of 500 response with standard engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, stackdriver

I have difficulties understanding why and how in a google app engine standard, sometimes I got the whole range of log levels I want and sometimes this range is "skipped" particularly after the response is a 500 error.

To reproduce that I created those 2 routes:

```
@app.route('/testlogger')
def testlogger():
    print(logging.getLogger().getEffectiveLevel())
    logger.critical(logging.CRITICAL)
    logger.error(logging.ERROR)
    logger.warning(logging.WARNING)
    logger.info(logging.INFO)
    logger.debug(logging.DEBUG)
    return 'ok', 200


@app.route('/testlogger500')
def testlogger500():
    print(logging.getLogger().getEffectiveLevel())
    logger.critical(logging.CRITICAL)
    logger.error(logging.ERROR)
    logger.warning(logging.WARNING)
    logger.info(logging.INFO)
    logger.debug(logging.DEBUG)
    return toto
```

The second one will purposely fail.

I then trigger alternatively both routes 3 times each

Below you'll see a screenshot of the stackdriver console.

On the first 3 hits on /testlogger the whole log range is reported as expected.

Then this becomes weird !

The first 3 subsequent hits on /testlogger500 report the whole log range on the first hit but not on the two after.

And then on each and every subsequent hits only the ERROR and CRITICAL ranges are sent to the stackdriver console, the WARNING, INFO and DEBUG are all screwed into the universe :)

For every route hit the logging.getLogger().getEffectiveLevel() is printed at 10, but it's as if once a 500 error was generated, stackdriver refused to show logs below ERROR.

[image: stackdriver logging]
[image: stackdriver logging caret]

Is that intended ? Once you get a backend error 500, no logs below ERROR are sent out or I'm doing something real fishy in here ?

Comment: can you click on the left caret to also display the app logs for a couple of the requests with inconsistent behaviour (collapse the non-relevant details so that they fit in the same screen)?

Comment: Hey @DanCornilescu, I edited my post and added a screen of the 1st non-consistent log, hope you get an idea what's going on :)

Comment: Well, you have a crash, the code no longer functions as you'd expect it to. This can explain missing app logs and unexpected return codes ( a crash will return a 500).

Comment: yes the crash is on purpose, still that doesn't explain why critical and error log level as long as simple print statements show up, and that kind of defeats the purpose of having debug logs in the 1st place if they dont show up when it crashes ! on the dev server all logs show up fine, crash or not

Comment: The crash *might* interfere with the logs distribution. Try without a crash.